# Outlook Crashes with Event ID 1000

Tags: vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2003, office-2003

We deployed a VSTO addin for outlook 2003. After installing the addin one of the user's outlook crashes when a contact is opened, i.e, when ItemProperties of the contact are read.Some theses properties are read using MAPI.There is no exception being logged even though we have try/catch and logging in all methods.

The event log has following message

```
The description for Event ID 1000 from source Microsoft Office 11 cannot be found
Source : Microsoft Office 11 
The following information was included with the event: 

outlook.exe
11.0.8312.0
4a403990
msvcr80.dll
8.0.50727.3053
4889d619
0
0001500a
```